# Mysql group by 1-15 and 16-30/31 days of a month

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with a lot of rows and i need to get the count of them grouped by ID and date bimonthly

For example

```
**ID   Date**    
15   2016/01/01    
15   2016/01/04    
15   2016/01/05    
15   2016/01/22    
15   2016/01/30    
15   2016/02/01    
15   2016/02/16    
15   2016/03/01    
15   2016/03/16    
15   2016/03/22
```

Expected results:

```
**Count    ID    Date**    
3          15    2016/01/01    
2          15    2016/01/15    
1          15    2016/02/01    
1          15    2016/02/15    
1          15    2016/03/01    
2          15    2016/03/15
```

Currently i have this:

```
SELECT count(*) as '#', ID, from_unixtime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date'    
FROM table    
GROUP BY country,WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(Date))    
ORDER BY Date
```

Which indeed groups by week but starting from the first input and so on (whici is not what i want but is as close as i have gotten)

EDIT: Changed the term to bimonthly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st thru 15th and 16th thru 30/31 groups are not "biweekly". That grouping would be referred to as bimonthly.  (I'd prefer the term "dimonthly" if that were a word.)

It's odd that you would want to return a value of the 15th, for the group that would not contain the 15th, rather than returning the 16th.

You could use expressions to get you the year and month, and then the 1st or 15th.

```
 GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.date,'%Y-%m-'),IF(DAY(t.date)<16,'01','15'))
          + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

You could use the same expression in the SELECT list to return the date value.

(My personal preference would be to return a date value of `yyyy-mm-16`, rather than `-15`.)

Note that this won't return a "zero count" for a bimonthly period where there aren't any rows. A row for such a period would be "missing".

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` clauses can be arbitrary expressions, e.g.

```
GROUP BY (DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(Date)) <= 15)
```

which would split things up into 1-15 and 16->

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it does group by days <= 15 but doesn't group by month so basically it counts all the inputs the first 15 days of every month

Comment: You can add GROUP BY date_format(date,'%y%m), (DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(Date)) <= 15) so it would be grouped by yearmonth and 1-15 and 16 onwards